# How to troubleshoot java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading a file that has ~500,000 records such as this

```
ROW_ID, COLOR_CODE, SHADE_ID
21, 22, 321
23, 31, 321
```

I load it like this:

```
 val colorSchema = StructType(Array(
         StructField("ROW_ID", IntegerType, true),
         StructField("COLOR_CODE", IntegerType, true),
         StructField("SHADE_ID", IntegerType, true)

     def makeSchema(filename:String, tableName:String,
         tableSchema:StructType,uri:String){

         val table = spark.read.
           format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
           option("header", "true").
           schema(tableSchema).load(uri+filename).cache()
         table.registerTempTable(tableName.toUpperCase)
       }

makeSchema("colors.csv","colors",colorSchema,"s3://bucket/")
```

The above code runs fine. However, when I run the following query I get an error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

```
val r = spark.sql("select * from colors where COLOR_CODE = 22").take(1)
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I spot this issue in an effective way? I have visually scanned the file to see if `COLOR_CODE` has missing values but I can't see any visually...

**Update**

I've asked a separate question that narrows down the problem further. The CSV now only has 1 row and I still get the same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564201/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-null-in-spark-sql

Comment: Somewhere a `String` is trying to be parsed into a numeric type, but the `String` is incorrectly formatted. I can't see where though.

Comment: I'm assuming that the SQL database is storing `ROW_ID`, `COLOR_CODE`, or `SHADE_ID` as a `varchar` instead of an `int`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: maybe related to this : https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/192

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have null/empty-values in your csv, or other strings which cannot be parsed to an int.

If the problems is with null-values, you can try this:

```
val table = spark.read.
           format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
           option("header", "true").
           option("nullValue","null").
           option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls,","true").
           schema(tableSchema).load(uri+filename).cache()
```

Answer (score 2):

Those whitespaces after the commas might be the issue.  Does your NFE look like this?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 22"
```

That's what happened to me when I recreated your issue.  Here's what fixed it:

```
    format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
    option("header", "true").
    option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY").
    option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true").
```

I believe you'll need to download univocity jar.  See http://www.univocity.com/